# Continuous Export of data in Azure Data Explorer to Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-storage-account

I am trying to configure automatic exports for data in Azure Data explorer to external tables in storage account. The external tables and continuous exports are created successfully (they show up when I run '.show external tables' and '.show continuous-exports' commands), but no data is being exported to the container.

Thinking it was a permission issue, I have tried, granting 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' to the identity of the Azure Data explorer instance and the identity used to create the continuous export.

Also, the SAS for the storage container is still valid. No idea why the data is not being exported. One-time export commands work fine.

Any ideas what I may be missing?

Answer (score 1):

A few things that come to mind:

1. Is your scenario hit one of the [continuous export limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/continuous-data-export#limitations)? For example, does your table uses streaming ingestion? (in that case support for this scenario is in public preview and you can open support ticket to enable it)
2. Did you get any failures? Check using [.show continuous export failures](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/show-continuous-failures)
3. Is there new data in the table that should be exported? Check the records that your query returns between the start cursor (that you get from `.show continuous export`) and the [current cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/cursorcurrent?pivots=azuredataexplorer).
4. If all fails open a support ticket.

Comment: Thanks for your input Avnera. I figured out it as because the table I was using to test was not ingesting any new records, hence no new exports were being sent.

Comment: thanks, feel free to mark it as an answer then :)